# JavaScript detect selection in Android browser

Tags: javascript, selection, detection, android-browser

How could I detect in **JavaScript** in the **Android Browser** the event when the user selects or changes the selection of some text and elements in the HTML page using JavaScript? Android browser won't dispatch touch end is such situation? Any ideas besides establishing a timer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recent WebKit has the `selectionchange` event on `document`. I've no idea if your Android's browser is recent enough, but you could give it a try.

```
document.addEventListener("selectionchange", function() {
    alert("Selection changed");
}, false);
```